# Unable to get elevation to change color of UI elements in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to make a dark theme UI following the design patterns laid out on: https://material.io/design/color/dark-theme.html. However, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get the color change to appear on the UI. I've tried setting clipToPadding and clipChildren to false to no avail, I've made sure hardware acceleration is turned on in the android manifest, the app theme is set to DayNight, moving the android:elevation="" to different places to see if that did the trick, and gave all the layouts involved a set background. I feel like I have to be missing something obvious here

Heres the xml file for the bar I want elevated:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/navBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@color/backgroundGrey">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/navBarButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/backgroundGrey"
        android:contentDescription="@string/navBarButtonContentDescription"
        android:tint="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.125"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_view_headline_24" />

    <!--TODO Make this an actual logo instead of just a placeholder-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/logoPlaceHolder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fitness Logo"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/navBarButton"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And heres where its located in the main activity file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@color/backgroundGrey"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    >

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/mainMenu"
        android:background="@color/backgroundGrey"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:clipChildren="false">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/backgroundGrey"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:clipChildren="false">

            <include layout="@layout/nav_bar_header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
                android:elevation="30dp">
            </include>
```

Comment: I don't think you can apply an elevation to an include tag.

Comment: I had tried this before without an include tag and it still didn't work (I hadn't split the main activity into different files yet), although I will take that into account for the future because I did not know that, thank you

Comment: Put a bottom margin on the element you apply the elevation to as well.  It needs to have room to draw the dropshadow, the margin will give it that.